# How to handle CSRF protection with Spring RESTful web services?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have a Spring web application with CSRF protection enabled. I am able to access the RESTful service via AJAX calls, but when I am accessing the service with other applications like httpurlconnection, I get a 401 error (CSRF token null).

I understand that to access the RESTful service I need to pass a token in the request header, but how can I get the CSRF token?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a mapping in Spring MVC that gets the CSRF token:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/csrf-token", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken)request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    return token.getToken();
}
```

Comment: I added this to my Spring back-end and I can geta  csrf-token.   Now the question is ... how do I pass this back to my Spring POST/PUT web-services?   I'd rather not make this part of my JSON data sending back.  I'd be more than happy to put the token in a header or as part of a cookie in the request.

Comment: @tjholmes66 You can send the token in a header named `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.

Comment: Yep.  Thanks.   I figured it out now.   Thanks!

Comment: I believe your answer basically undermines CSRF protection. It enables an attacker to fetch CSRF token at will by performing the get request.

Comment: @UMad As long as same-origin policy is enforced it should be ok.