# how to get csrf token into spring controller?

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, spring-4

I am trying to return CSRF token from a REST controller with spring 4 with xml based configuration.

I have tried this:

```
@RestController
public class Somecontroller{
@RequestMapping("/csrf")
public CsrfToken csrf(CsrfToken token) {
    return token;
}
}
```

But I just get a 404. What am I missing?
Everything else is working, as I can log initially.

Comment: have you enabled @EnableWebSecurity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Spring CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125598/how-to-access-spring-csrf-restful-web-service).

Comment: I am using xml based configuration for spring security (not annotation based), from what I have read on the web, it is suposed to be enabled. Also, the linked question is about sending the token from client to server. I need to let know the client the value of a token instead. I read that a controller should be able to get the token as a parameter to the mapping method, but when I add such method and try to access it, I get 404 status error.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to inform the client of the csrf value.
I have seen examples where csrf is read from the session attributes with a name "_csrf". Which strikes me as odd and prone to being changed in the future.

However I ended up going with that.

Comment: I have seen some users using `CsrfToken requestToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());` instead.