# How to get CSRF token from the GET /csrf endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csrf

My goal is to add CSRF to STOMP headers.

What I've tried and it does work, but I am not sure whether I should use this or not as I do not found this solution on the Spring Security Reference:

1. Use cookie (send request to any unprotected GET endpoint to get the CSRF token)

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
  }
}
```

What I've tried:

1. Create GET /csrf endpoint by following [the official reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#websocket-sameorigin-csrf):

CsrfController.java

```
@RestController
public class CsrfController {

  @RequestMapping("/csrf")
  public CsrfToken csrf(CsrfToken token) {
    return token;
  }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity // for endpoint GET /csrf to work.
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/csrf").permitAll();
  }
}
```

2. Followed [this marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125598/how-to-handle-csrf-protection-with-spring-restful-web-services) on SO.

CsrfController.java

```
@RestController
public class CsrfController {

  @RequestMapping("/csrf")
  public String csrf(HttpServletRequest request) {
    CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken)request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    return token.getToken();
  }
}
```

My expected result is: The GET /csrf endpoint return the token value.

My actual result is: The response is "Internal Server Error", and an error log.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfToken - and no default constructor found either
```

Comment: Note: What kind of authentication do you use for your requests?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I use `http.formLogin()` by overriding the `configure(HttpSecurity http) method`

Comment: Okay, so this is a cookie-based Web application that does in fact require CSRF. Just checking to confirm that.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am still learning Spring Security, I plan to use Spring Security and Spring WebSocket for my mobile app. Am I on the right track to use `cookie-based` CSRF?

Comment: I can't advise for your particular situation, I'm afraid. It's not generally a good idea, I don't think, because it triggers on the same cross-site requests.